# Error while exec kubectl get po -o yaml in golang example

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

How to get Kubectl get po -o yaml in golang

it to run this code
[Go client example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration)

where the expected output is

```
./app
There are 3 pods in the cluster
There are 3 pods in the cluster
There are 3 pods in the cluster
```

but when i run it i got

```
 go build -o app .
    ./app
panic: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/padmanabanpr/Documents/client-go/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go:61 +0x5b6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to your k8s client/server version being higher than 1.24+
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920 Please refer this for further clarification

Comment: my client and server k8s versions are v1.20.5 and v1.20.15-eks-14c7a48

Answer (score 0):

the following steps fixed the issue

- install Kubectl client 1.23.0-00(there is some problem with 1.24.x)

```
$ cd client-go/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration
$ go mod init example.com/m
$ go mod tidy
$ go build -o app .
$ ./app
```